# How can i print only index values as a list ? from below line

Tags: pandas

This line is giving me all columns of my file. I am trying to print only `price` list(index only which contains `med`) of this line.

```
df.loc[df['price'].str.contains("med")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df[df['price'].str.contains("med")].index
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
df.index[df['price'].str.contains("med")]
```